# How to call JSP tags in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

Is it allowed to call JSP tags inside JavaScript file like the following example which uses Spring MVC tags:

```js
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

function displayErrors() {  
   alert("<form:errors path='*'>");
}
```

If allowed, how to make it work correctly?

Comment: jstl script noway, doesn't work, use it in jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is JSP

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<script>
function displayErrors() {  
   alert("<form:errors path='*'>");
}
</script>
```

---

You can use JSP tags inside JSP file, not JS file.